# How to best remove "struct" import cycles?

Tags: go

I'm playing with converting an old project that needs a rewrite into Go. 
Most of my initial attempts have been looking successful but I've run into a problem with import cycles.

My project structure looks like this:

```
model
  orgs
    org.go
  events
    event.go
  shows    
    show.go
  entries
    exhibitor.go
    entry.go
  fees
  premiums
  etc.
```

There are typically 3-8 go files in each leaf directory.
There are currently 9 child directories under model. That will about double.

Here's the problem part. Each .go file typically contains a struct like this:

```
import (
    "model/shows"
)
type Event struct {
    ownerOrg *orgs.Org // reference back to the sponsoring organization
    showList []*Show   // list of each show in the event
}
```

.

```
import (
    "model/entries"
    "model/events"
)
type Show struct {
    ownerEvent    *events.Event               // reference back to the owner event
    exhibitorList []*entries.Exhibitor // list of exhibitors entered in the show
}
```

.

```
import (
    "model/shows"
)
type Exhibitor struct {
    ownerShow *shows.Show            // reference back to the owner show
    entryList []*entries.Entry // list of entries for this exhibitor
}
```

Having the back reference and the forward lists is giving me cycle issues.

Note: there are often more than one "owner" type references in each struct and almost always more then one "list" slices in each struct. This just compounds the problem.

Here's what I've tried and my best current solution (which is okay but not very Go-ish).

1. **Factoring to interfaces.**
   This is the "typically" import cycle solution I see. It doesn't seem appropriate (or even possible?) when the problem is **structural** rather than **behavioral**.
2. **Change "owners" to be interfaces.**
   I'm pretty sure this I could get this to work but seems to lead to a worse structure. It would have lots of type conversion and factoring out behaviors into weird .go files. Code no longer "near" where it's expected or used. This would leave me with what I'd consider a difficult structure for other coders to understand and use with no gain except to make the compiler happy.
3. **Big ball-o-mud.**
   Just put all the 50+ .go files into one package. This solves the cycle problem but creates readability and understanding problems.
4. **Unorthodox prefixes.** (My current thinking.)
   I can combine the big ball-o-mud with directory prefixes so I end up with this structure:

.

```
model
  orgs_org.go
  events_event.go
  shows_show.go
  entries_exhibitor.go
  entries_entry.go
  etc.
```

Outside of having not seen it, is it really terrible or just "odd?" 
It does seemingly solve my problem and it keeps functionality where it's expected and where it's used.

Is there a better "Go way" that anyone knows for this (typical to me) business object structure?

Comment: With them being so interdependent like this, there isn't much reason to try to break them into separate packages, as you've already noticed, this is difficult. One could feasibly separate them into as discrete packages as possible, but that really just depends on how interconnected they are. What are you trying to accomplish by breaking your models into different packages?

Comment: as @RayfenWindspear says above, this is about the contents of your files and the meaning they have, so you can spread your code in packages, each package containing sources that share a "common funcionallity"; the keypoint here (i think) is that the "common functionallity" is something that belongs to the problem's domain and you shall discover by performing the appropiate domain analysis. I guess you shall put, for a start, what is complaining about the compller and to show the rest of the project, enabling any of us to provide you a suggestion for an _arbitrary_ package layout

Comment: @RayfenWindspear Really, just to make it easy for others to find code. There will probably be over 80 files in the "one" package otherwise. Putting in descriptive subdirectories gives others a sensible place to start looking for where particular code is likely to be found.

Comment: Yeah, normally your initial structure would work fine, but the wrench thrown in here is the back references. At best (AFAIK, mind you) you'll just have to bundle the interconnected ones, but you could easily separate other disconnected models as you originally wanted. I struggled with something like this a while back, but I don't have access to that code anymore, and I believe I eventually broke down and just bundled the models.

Comment: @Victor The problem is import cycles. In the example above, Event -> Show -> Exhibitor -> Show etc. In this case I've distilled out ALL the "common functionality" ... there is none, just pure struct cyclical references.

Comment: Might you add a new `types` package and move all of these structs into that, leaving the rest of the code where it is? I know of languages where that's a common practice, I'm not sure if it is in Go.

Comment: @WillRubin believe me that i know how hard can be to layout your files in go packages, generally speaking (leaving golang aside) i would say that code organization can be as hard as it is to understand a problem's domain. So... may be, Event, Show and Exhibitior are things that should be placed under one package, as they must cooperate in order to provide an unit of functionally. Recall that the criteria for making packages is purely arbitrary.